# Change id of FormBuilder - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, registration, fosuserbundle

I created a registration form using the command formbuilder.
I tried this but it does not change my identifier

```
{{form_widget (form.nombreUsuario, {'attr': {'id': 'signup-firstname'}})}}
```

And appears in html:

```
<input id="fos_user_registration_form_nombreUsuario" type="text" tabindex="1" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="form.nombreUsuario" required="required" name="fos_user_registration_form[nombreUsuario]">
```

My RegistrationFormType is:

```
    namespace Train\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {  
        //parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
         $builder->add('nombreUsuario', 'text', array('required' => 'true',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'form.nombreUsuario', 'autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'tabindex' => '1'
            )));         
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'train_user_registration';
    }

}
```

And my app/config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Train\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: train_user_registration
```

My UserBundle/services.yml

```
services:
    train_user.registration.form.type:
        class: Train\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: train_user_registration }
```

Thank you very much for your time,

Alejandro

Answer (score 2):

You can specify an id in **twig**

```
{{ form_widget (form.nombreUsuario, {'id' : 'signup-firstname'}) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can`t change id for fields into fosuserbundle **BUT** you can add a class

try this :

```
namespace Train\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {  
        //parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
         $builder->add('nombreUsuario', 'text', array('required' => 'true',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'form.nombreUsuario', 
                        'autofocus' => 'autofocus', 
                        'tabindex' => '1',
                        'class' => 'signup-firstname'  // your class for form_widget    
            )));         
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'train_user_registration';
    }

}
```

or in twig :

```
{{form_widget (form.nombreUsuario, {'attr': {'class': 'signup-firstname'} }) }}
```

Comment: I tried but still not working. Appears fos_user_registration_form_nombreUsuario

Comment: i think you can`t override id for fields into fosuserbundle,
check update in my answer

Comment: Looking to have found this site but does not change the identifier. I do not know how to fix it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859315/how-to-overriding-fosuserbundle-registration-form-style?rq=1

Comment: you can only add class to field but you can`t change id of field